# Mapeamento de Herança Type per Type Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, herança, asp.net-identity

Em meu projeto, possuo um tipo de herança que mapeei por TPT. Analisando os documentos e vários exemplos não consigo identificar onde estou errando, pois o mapeamento aparentemente está correto, as definições das classes, tudo.

Problema: Possuo três classes: Pessoa, Cliente e Corretor. Cliente e Corretor herdam de Pessoa e assim está no mapeamento. 
Quando no sistema faço qualquer busca utilizando o DbSet das subclasses, a query que o identity monta é buscando da classe pai, ou seja, se fiz uma busca utilizando o tipo Cliente, o identity monta uma query partindo da superclasse (Pessoa) e não da subclasse (Cliente).

```
public abstract class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa()
    {
    }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string NumeroCpfCnpj { get; set; }
    public string NumeroRgIe { get; set; }
    public string FlagEstadoCivil { get; set; }
    public string Profissao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDeNascimento { get; set; }
    public string TelefoneFixo { get; set; }
    public string TelefoneCelular { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string NomeMae { get; set; }
    public string NomePai { get; set; }
    public string NomeConjuge { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimentoConjuge { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCasamento { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public float RendaFamiliar { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
    public int? CidadeId { get; set; }
    public string Observacoes { get; set; }
    public int RegimeCasamentoId { get; set; }
    public int EstadoCivilId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }
    public string OrgaoEmissor { get; set; }
    public string EstadoEmitente { get; set; }
    public Sexo Sexo { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente : Pessoa
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        FlagMauPagador = false;
        StatusCobrancaId = 1;
        FlagImpedirRealizarVenda = false;
        FlagImpedirGerarBoleto = false;
        FlagImpedirSairNoRelatorioCobranca = false;
    }

    public bool FlagMauPagador { get; set; }
    public int StatusCobrancaId { get; set; }
    public bool FlagImpedirRealizarVenda { get; set; }
    public bool FlagImpedirGerarBoleto { get; set; }
    public bool FlagImpedirSairNoRelatorioCobranca { get; set; }
}


public class Corretor : Pessoa
{
    public Corretor()
    {
        Produtos = new List<Produto>();
        Loteamentos = new List<Loteamento>();
    }

    public int CodCorretor { get; set; }
    public string NomeCorretor { get; set; }
    public string Creci { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorDescontoMaximo { get; set; }
    public int? IdParceiroVenda { get; set; }
    public bool flgAtivo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Loteamento> Loteamentos { get; set; }
}


public class PessoaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public PessoaConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("pessoa");

        HasKey(c => c.Id);

        Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnName("cod_pessoa")
            .IsRequired();

        [...]

     }
}

 public class CorretorConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Corretor>
{
    public CorretorConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("corretor");

       [...]
    }
}


public class ClienteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("cliente");

          [...]
     }
}
```

Comment: Como está configurado o seu `DbContext` Coloque toda a classe na pergunta? e suas classes também e qual código se está realizando a pesquisa?

Comment: E as consultas e o DbContext????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observação:** *Tem ajustes a fazer, na classe abstrata `Pessoa` tem que possuir a `Id` que tem a finalidade de gerar o código identificador da tabela Pessoa e que será utilizado para gravar nas tabelas Cliente e Corretor que também possui um campo de `Id` mas, não é auto incremento, inclusive em `Corretor` não precisa ter o campo `CodCorretor` é para remover*

```
public abstract class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa()
    {
    }
    public int Id { get; set; } // campo a ser inserido
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string NumeroCpfCnpj { get; set; }
    public string NumeroRgIe { get; set; }
    public string FlagEstadoCivil { get; set; }
    public string Profissao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDeNascimento { get; set; }
    public string TelefoneFixo { get; set; }
    public string TelefoneCelular { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string NomeMae { get; set; }
    public string NomePai { get; set; }
    public string NomeConjuge { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimentoConjuge { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCasamento { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public float RendaFamiliar { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
    public int? CidadeId { get; set; }
    public string Observacoes { get; set; }
    public int RegimeCasamentoId { get; set; }
    public int EstadoCivilId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }
    public string OrgaoEmissor { get; set; }
    public string EstadoEmitente { get; set; }
    public Sexo Sexo { get; set; }
}
```

*Já nas classes* `Corretor` *e* `Cliente` *não precisa ter esse campo `Id`, somente nas tabelas como explicado na observação.*

*Reconfigure a parte do mapeamento das 3 classes, referente as mudanças*

---

Para ter o efeito esperado deve-se agora criar um classe herdando do [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx) com o seguinte código:

```
public class Database : DbContext
{
    public Database()
        :base("connectionString") { }      

    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa {get;set;}
}
```

Para inserir dados crie classes

```
Database db = new Database();

Cliente c = new Cliente();
c. ... // aqui sãos os campos e seus valores

db.Pessoa.Add(c);
db.SaveChanges();
```

***e***

```
Corretor co = new Corretor();
co. ... // aqui sãos os campos e seus valores

db.Pessoa.Add(co);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Para recuperar as informações deve utilizar o metodo [`OfType<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb301729(v=vs.110).aspx) oferecendo o tipo corresponde para recuperação (que no caso é `Cliente` ou `Corretor`), ***exemplo***:

```
//Corretor
Corretor co = db.Pessoa.OfType<Corretor>().where(c => c.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

//Cliente
Cliente c = db.Pessoa.OfType<Cliente>().where(c => c.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Um exemplo claro seria nesse [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt), que pode ser utilizado como exemplo também.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Entity Framework Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Método ObjectQuery.OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb301729(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)
- [Entity Framework Designer TPT Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618293(v=vs.113).aspx)